# Preference Style Table Views (like when selecting your ringtone)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to create a table like the one where you choose your ringtone in the Settings app. I'd like to implement it like it is often done in third party apps, where once a selection is made, the navigation controller slides the selection screen to the right to reveal the preferences screen again, as soon as the ringtone is selected.

What's different in my desired implementation, is that there will be no preferences screen, just a series of selection screens that the user will progress through, differently depending on what the previous selection is.

I am mostly wondering how to make a table like in the selection screen as I cannot seem to find any documentation/samples like it (perhaps I don't quite know how to phrase the search as it seems like there should be some resources out there about this). I am quite certain I can figure out the rest, but any additional input would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I really messed that one up - that was the code for a checklist: - This is the code for a radio button style settings pane:

Where selected is an int ivar/property holding the last selected value:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int newRow = [indexPath row];

    if (newRow != selected) {
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        NSIndexPath *oldIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selected inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndex];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        selected = [indexPath row];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newRow forKey:key];

    // Then in your case you would add:
    [self.navigationController popViewController];
}
```

Sorry for messing it up the first time!

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems pretty simple after seeing it.